# Junaio second quickstarts example not working

Tags: channel, junaio

Maybe this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to get the second GLUE_2_AnimationsAndGLue example from the junaio quickstarts to work. I uploaded the needed folders (ARELLibrary and GLUE_2_AnimationsAndGLue) to my webserver, NEXT to each other, as suggested (and from the code logic i can see that's the way they need to be uploaded).
But still when i validate my channel i get the following error:

```
XML Parsing Error: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Extra content at the end of the document in Entity, line: 3
```

If someone has encountered this difficulty and knows a solution, please share.

Note: I am using 000webhost.com free web hosting, if it somehow matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on the metaio forum, and a Software Engineer at metaio / junaio pointed out that my hosting provider adds additional content at the end of the response:

```
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

You can see this if you click on the 'Show request response' when you validate your channel. It seems that this was the problem or the extra content the error was referring to. 000webhost.com gives you the possibility of disabling this analytics code very easily, and after that everything works fine. Thx metaio